# SQL select a column and add

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables RBL and region.

```
Select *, r.RegionId
from RBL b
left join region r 
on r.Name = b.Region_name
```

After left join, I want to add the RegionId column into RBL.

Comment: where you want to add ...in select it will come as last column..

Comment: I want to permanently add into RBL table

Comment: Either you first add an empty column to the `RBL` table and then `UPDATE` its value or you create another table with the resul of the join

Comment: @Lamak     update RBL
    set RegionId = (Select r.RegionId
    from region r 
    left join RBL b
    on r.Name = b.Region_name
    ) Tried this but error occurs..

Comment: @HeatherWon what is your rdbms?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza sql server.

Comment: So why the tag vlookup?

Comment: @HeatherWon That's not the syntax for an update with a join. And does `RegionId` exists on the `RBL` table?

Comment: @Lamak yes I added an empty column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you update your table to include a new field `RegionId`

**[ALTER TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)**

Then update the table

```
UPDATE RBL 
SET RegionId =  (SELECT  r.RegionId
                 FROM region r 
                 WHERE r.Name = RBL.Region_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an empty column, you need to update its value:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.RegionId = B.RegionId
FROM RBL A
INNER JOIN Region B
   ON A.Region_name = B.Name;
```

Comment: This will assing `NULL` or leave the same value for no match row?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza If there's no match, then there's no result for the `INNER JOIN`, leaving the row empty